# polymer select values not set

Tags: javascript, select, nested, polymer

I've setup a JSbin to show an issue I'm having with a polymer select box not reflecting the model (initially), however, the model does get updated after selecting an option. Note that in my example, I'm ensuring the model is loaded after the select options are populated, however, I guess the tricky thing here is that the select box population is a nested dom-repeat  (thus when module is populated, the nested dom-repeat for the 'select' must be re-populated - I'm guessing).

Here's the bin and how to test it to show the dilemma.

http://jsbin.com/xucavi/edit?html,console,output

After page loads, note there are no selections made in the 2 select boxes.  Click the 'Display Values from Model' button. Note that the values show the model has values.  Select 'Digital' for each of the 2 select boxes.  Now click the 'Display Values from Model' button again - and note that model has been updated.

Any thoughts on how to work around this?  Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what different behavior you expect. What do you mean by "not reflecting the model"?

Comment: When the screen initially loads, the model (array of objects containing book data) has values set for book type, but the select boxes do not reflect this.  But the binding is working (after initial display anyways).

Comment: Have you verified that this way of selecting an option does actually work. AFAIK you need to set the `selected` attribute on the option element.

Comment: yeah - that does work. Setting 'selected' on options is not needed (handled by the framework). However, the combination of 1.) the options being bound dynamically (via a dom-repeat) and 2.) being inside an outer dom-repeat  - causes issues  (because inner dom-repeat is re-bound when outer dom-repeat is bound -- personally think this is a bug in the framework because I think it should still work under those circumstances). For now, I'll use the solution presented below as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute the value for the `selected` attribute of the `option` elements.

Modify the outer `dom-repeat` to bind the actual books to the property `book` instead of `item`. Now, binding the `selected` attribute to a `_computeSelected(item, book)` function makes it possible to dynamically calculate the selected book type:

```
<option value='{{item.id}}' selected$='[[_computeSelected(item, book)]]'>{{item.type}}</option>
```

The implementation of the function itself is quite simple:

```
_computeSelected: function(item, book) {
    return item.id === book.typeId;
}
```

Working example of your JS Bin: 
http://jsbin.com/sodugigubo/edit?html,console,output

For a more in depth explanation, read about [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) and [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding).

**Warning**: Be aware that [Polymer dom repeat is not working for Select Option in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199859/polymer-dom-repeat-is-not-working-for-select-option-in-ie).